# No more power button

Tags: shutdown

Since yesterday I don't have the icon to shutdown my computer to the upper right of my screen.

I can't find any solution.

Any idea ?

Comment: Have you tried? `sudo apt-get install wingpanel --reinstall`

Comment: `Reinstallation of wingpanel is not possible, it cannot be downloaded.`

Comment: I notice a similar issue after some OS update. Can't remember which update exactly but a reboot returned everything to normal.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
sudo apt-get install indicator-session
```

Then reboot and it should be there again